# Get Artifactory stored file checksum via BASH

Tags: artifactory

I have a file stored in Artifactory.  I need to get its checksum without downloading it.

Need to use BASH.

```
url="http://$abc/$def/$qwe/file.a?properties"
curl -u "$user":AP"$pass" "$url"
```

does not work.  I get error that there are no properties.  The file exists, has checksum, and path is correct.

Would be nice to get MD5 checksum into a var and check if command succeeded or not.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ItemProperties

Example:

```
curl http://artifactory.host/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme
```

You could pipe it to jq (which is a commandline JSON parser) and take only the checksum you need.

```
curl http://artifactory.host/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme | | jq .checksums.sha1
```

Other option is to simply perform a HEAD request with curl:

```
curl -I http://$abc/$def/$qwe/file.a
```

And then grep for the checksum you want.

Comment: Hi, the jq code did not work...  The last suggestion with -I did work.  However, doesn't the -I option actually download the file?  I don't want to download the file...

Comment: -I for curl performs http HEAD request which only shows headers. From the curl man page '-I, --head          Show document info only'.

Comment: What did not work with jq? it might not been installed. You will have to install it on the machine running the command. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 3):

You can use this [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FileInfo) to get the file info, and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters) to filter out the MD5.

For example:

```
url="http://localhost:8081/artifactory"
pathToFile="path/to/file"
curl -u "$user":"$pass" "$url/api/storage/$pathToFile" | jq '.checksums.md5'
```